# one form instead of two with jquery with show/hide radio button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

my problem is simple, i want to show one form instead of two that is currently, i mean i want to hide or show some fields depending on the selection 
when individual is selected i want to show 4 fields(name,surname,afm,email) and when corporation is selected i want to hide(name,surname) and show in place companyname input field and keep the afm,email input fields. so to use ONE form! instead of two.
Currently my code has TWO forms... is working.. but i want to use ONE form  , so here is my code fot the jquery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name$='forma']").click(function() {
    var formma = $(this).val();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#Forma" + formma).show();
      });
    });
   </script>
```

and the html with the 2 forms,,but as i said i want one form instead cause in for future use will be added more fields!

```
    <div class="filtering">         
      <div id="myFormGroup">    
Individual<input type="radio" name="forma" checked="checked" value="2"  />    
Company<input type="radio" name="forma" value="3" />    
   <div id="Forma2" class="desc">
    <div class="idiotisReg">
     <form id="frmIdiotisCompany" name="frmIdiotisCompany" onSubmit="return checkForm()" method="post" target="_top">             
        <table width="85%" border="0">
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisNa">Individual Form</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisNa">Name</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="individualName" name="individualName"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisSu">Surname</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="individualSurname" name="individualSurname"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisAf">AFM</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="Afm" name="Afm"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisEm">Email</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="Email" name="idiotisCompanyEmail"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th height="54" scope="col"></br></th>
            <th scope="col"><button name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" style="text-align: right" >Submit</button></br></th>
           </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
     <div id="Forma3" class="desc" style="display: none;">
     <div class="idiotisReg">
     <form id="frmIdiotisCompany" name="frmIdiotisCompany" onSubmit="return checkForm()" method="post" target="_top">             
        <table width="85%" border="0">
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisNa">Company Form</span></th>
           </tr>
            <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisNa">Company Name</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisAf">AFM</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="Afm" name="Afm"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col"><span id="idiotisEm">Email</span>:</th>
             <th scope="col"><input type="text" size="75" id="Email" name="Email"></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th height="54" scope="col"></br></th>
            <th scope="col"><button name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" style="text-align: right" >Submit</button></br></th>
           </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

i believe i have to change my jquery and my divs in the html but what and were ? any help would be really appreciated

Comment: You can add the directive [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng/directive/ngShow) in the divs you want to hide/show.

Comment: thank you  denisazevedo really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i managed to do it with one form! by changing the jquery to (just in case anyone else need it..

```
   //showhide function on the 1 forma with 2 divs
   $("input[name$='type']").click(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
  if(value=='Individual') {
   // $("#Individual_box").show();
  $("#Individual_box").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
 $("#Company_box").hide();
 }
 else if(value=='Company') {
// $("#Company_box").show();
 $("#Company_box").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
  $("#Individual_box").hide();
 }
 });
$("#Individual_box").show();
$("#Company_box").hide();  
});
```

and changed the html **to one form** as following

```
 <h1>Εγγραφή Ιδιώτη ή Επιχείρησης</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="form1">
  <p>
   <label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Individual" id="type_0" checked="checked" />
  Ιδιώτης</label>
   <label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Company" id="type_1" />
  Επιχείρηση</label>
  </p>
 <div id="Individual_box">
  <p>
  <label>Όνομα</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
 </p>
  <p>
  <label>Επώνυμο</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <label>Α.Φ.Μ. Ιδιώτη</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <label>E-mail Ιδιώτη</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
</p>
</div>
<div id="Company_box">
<p>
  <label>Επωνυμία Επιχείρησης</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
  <label>Α.Φ.Μ. Επιχείρησης</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
</p>
<p>
  <label>E-mail Επιχείρησης</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" />
</p>
</div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Καταχώρηση" />
</p>
```

```
   topic closed thank you once again all of you
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code I found a couple of syntax errors. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("input[name='forma']").click(function(){
          var formma = $(this).val();
          $("div.desc").hide();
          $("#Forma" + formma).show();
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Viswanath D but i believe you posted exactly my same jquery code on above... thank you anyway for the help.. :)

Comment: @dc03kks Hey not the exact code, I have made small syntax corrections. Check it..!!